# Tomcat Unable to Connect

Tags: centos, tomcat

I have done a fresh install of Tomcat 7 on CentOS 6.2 system. Tomcat starts successfully without any errors in logs, but I am not able to access it on mydomain.com:8080. I get "cannot connect" message. The port is definitely not blocked (I have not yet setup any firewall) and the server is running.

Any suggestions what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Hmm, so many things can be wrong.  `netstat -an |grep 8080` to start, to see if the tomcat process is actually listening on port 8080 on an available interface.  Also, `host mydomain.com` to make sure you're hitting the IP you expect to hit for the server.

Comment: When I issue `netstat -an |grep 8080` this is when tomcat is stopped: `tcp 0 0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8080 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:34483 TIME_WAIT` and this is when tomcat is running: `tcp 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN`. The IP address is correct.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an external firewall?  Port 8080 is atypical for hosting services to open up, if they're restricting themselves to 22, 80 and 443.  Also, if this is an EC2 instance, you would probably need to add that port into the Security Group that applies.  Also, from where are you testing?  From the box itself, some other machine on the network, through the Internet?  Please update your Question with that info.

Comment: What's listening on `8080` while Tomcat is stopped?  Check `lsof -i`.

Comment: can you provide your server.xml? You have to configure tomcate to listen on mydomain.com:8080 in the server.xml. DOes it work when you try localhost?

Comment: I am getting the same `tcp 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN`, but browsing to localhost:8080 returns nothing, and the log does not show any attempted connection.

Comment: UPDATE, did a manual update from 6 to 7 and now it works.  Same output from `netstat`.